# Ошибка error (1,0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, мобильная-разработка

Подскажите пожалуйста пытаюсь к существующему приложению в android studio  добавить аутентификацию через Firebase. При изменении фалов build.gradle вышла следующая ошибка error (1,0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found?
P.S. ниже измененный код

---

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.danil.smssecurity"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте как в доке написано вот это `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` в конец файла перенести

Comment: не помогло....та же самая ошибка

Comment: Ещё, вы, кажется, удалили андроидовский плагин `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` (версию не знаю какую вам надо - студия сама подскажет или смотрите в истории изменений файла какая была пока вы её не удалили) - он должен быть рядом с `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'`